# Keep a very rough text mode in a non graphical Debian instance

Tags: debian, resolution

I installed Debian for a server purpose and I do not need a good quality text mode. I would like to keep the very rough bad resolution text mode that is appearing just after a grub choice screen. Just going to get a minimal system.

How to achieve it?

### Update

I am being getting many questions what the question actually mean. So please watch the yt link
https://youtu.be/cTK3aIZbe2A?t=39

You can see a text

```
[blabla,blabla]kvm: disabled by bios
[blabla,blabla]kvm: disabled by bios
```

It is displayed in a bad small, resolution. Isn't it?
But in some milliseconds the text and lines upon it are changing to the better resolution! It happens in about one second but you can see it.

My question is how to avoid this resolution change and keep initial bad resolution

### Update 2

I am not sure that my aim is clear so I prepared an image that may help. On the image one can see two text modes of a screen during Debian initialization.  The upper is more rough and the lower is more elegant. The upper is earlier then the lower. I want to keep this rough one and prevent the system from changing it during boo time. So after the boot time it is still like this upper one.

[image]

Comment: What’s wrong with the higher-resolution text mode you presumably end up with?

Comment: The question needs to state which platform this is, and how you think that just changing KVTs between two text modes makes any difference to the size of the system.

Comment: @StephenKitt I dont't know. The question is how to get rid of it.

Comment: @JdeBP What do you mean platform? I need pure rough text mode. The higher resolution is useless improvement.

Comment: Make up your mind on what your metric is.  Is your goal to avoid "improvement"? Or is it to be a "minimal" system?  Or are you simply changing stuff without understanding it or having a thought-through goal?  And tell answerers what platform this is.  They are not telepathic and don't know whether you are using Debian on an embedded system with a 50×15 LCD display.

Comment: I have two Debian boxes. The goal of the first is to get rid of improvements and the second to get minimal system. I want to avoid getting a higher resolution text mode i their non graphical systems. I have 200 x 15 LCD displays.

Comment: @trzczy Do you want to reduce text rendering resolution to have a more minimal system or because your monitor is so low resolution that the higher resolution text is unreadable?

Comment: @kemotep Only because of aesthetic reasons and for my education of a field of Debian

Comment: @trzczy what have you tried and what is not working? Please edit your post to include all of these details and specifically point out what your goals are. Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep I tried nothing because did not find an advice nor tutorial.

Comment: Is the advice listed [here](https://varlock.net/how-to-change-resolution-on-grub-and-tty/) and [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2018/1/how-change-your-linux-console-fonts) what you are trying to do? Most people try to increase the font resolution and screen resolution of the boot screen for a sharper image. It is no wonder you found no advice or tutorial in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to disable modesetting. Edit `/etc/default/grub` to add

```
nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0
```

to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, then run

```
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

as root, and reboot.